# why can't I retrieve the track of my Spotify playlist even i have given correct full xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, spotify

I was trying to scrap links of my playlist songs using scrapy in Spotify website, without using Spotify API ,but iam stuck at accessing the elements through xpath ,I have checked the xpath ,which I copied using full xpath of the element from Google developer tools
and it is showing correctly in developer tool but not returning any response while I run the ipython shell , is there a way to parse the path correctly?

I tried response.xpath("//div[@class='main']") ,it gives response but can't get to next div even though.given response.xpath("//div[@class='main']/div[@class='root']")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your question is essentially saying "I did everything right but it didn't work". That doesn't help us establish what you did wrong.

Comment: sure as it was my first time in stack overflow and scrapy i didn't know what ask properly.

Comment: i wanted to scrap my spotify playlist webpage [link](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1vrKjPGdovHJjBEPWppeZU) for my college project , i am using scrapy and scrapy shell to retrieve the URLs of my playlist songs,  ---->firstly,i fetched the html of webpage in shell use fetch command i.e 'fetch("https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1vrKjPGdovHJjBEPWppeZU")' .

Comment: ---->then , i identified the xpath of the first song by using developer tools i.e '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a' .  ---->then i run the command in shell to get the response i.e ' response.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[3]/d 
   ...: iv[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a/@href").extract()'  but it returned no results  ---> i just want to know how to get the URLs of tracks in my playlist

Comment: (note ::iam not using the spotify api to scrapy)

Comment: Using [spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/) much easy then scrapy.